# Button @Directive to bind disable attribute via @Input in Angular

Tags: angular, directive

I'm trying to create a button directive that can receive a boolean via `@Input` and get bound to the `disable` attribute of the `<button>` element.

Here's what I've got so far:

**loading-button.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appLoadingButton]' })
export class LoadingButtonDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() loaderState: boolean;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', this.loaderState ? 'disabled' : '');
  }
}
```

**template**

```
<button appLoadingButton [loaderState]="submitting"></button>
```

In that template's component, the `submitting` property is set to `true` or `false` when convenient.

My problem is that this way it is always disabled and I was expecting that the disable attribute was dynamically changing with the directive.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well you only set the attribute onInit and since it is not defined as observable, than you never change the state back and forth

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are multiple options. One would be to use `@HostBinding`, and that would be all you need for this:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appLoadingButton]' })
export class LoadingButtonDirective {
  @Input() 
  @HostBinding('disabled')
  loaderState: boolean;
}
```

Comment: @Genís you're welcome :) 99.9% of the time you really don't need the renderer